# KSQL: table key column is not the column used in the join criteria

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'd like to join two KSQL tables with one to many relationship on a column that is different from the key.
How can I do that?
I'll give an example, a context, a solution I started working on, and the problems I encountered.

## Example

A single team can have many players, and the join should be on `teams.name = players.team`:

`teams`:

```
| name     | founded | arena          | championships |
|----------|---------|----------------|---------------|
| eagles   | 2020    | at&t arena     | 0             |
| vultures | 2019    | verizon center | 1             |
```

`players`:

```
| name     | team     | avg_points | born |
|----------|----------|------------|------|
| alice    | vultures | 30         | 2013 |
| bob      | vultures | 25         | 2015 |
| charlie  | eagles   | 20         | 2014 |
```

Desired result - `players_teams_enriched`:

```
| player   | team     | avg_points | born | team_founded | arena          | team_championships |
|----------|----------|------------|------|--------------|----------------|--------------------|
| alice    | vultures | 30         | 2013 | 2019         | verizon center | 1                  |
| bob      | vultures | 25         | 2015 | 2019         | verizon center | 1                  |
| charlie  | eagles   | 20         | 2014 | 2020         | at&t arena     | 0                  |
```

## Context

#### Set up the infrastructure

The following assumes you have confluent platform 5.4.0 and mysql db locally. Briefly:

```sh
# Run confluent platform in docker:
git clone git@github.com:confluentinc/examples
# add mysql driver and connector before starting docker compose, then:
cd examples/cp-all-in-one && docker-compose up -d
# connect as a client:
docker run -it --rm --name ksql-cli-1 --network cp-all-in-one_default confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.4.0 http://ksql-server:8088

# Run mysql in docker:
# create the docker network if it doesn't exist yet
docker network inspect cp-all-in-one_default &>/dev/null || docker network create --driver bridge cp-all-in-one_default
# create the container
docker run --name mysql --network cp-all-in-one_default -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=example -e MYSQL_USER=demouser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=demopass -d mysql
# connect as a client
docker run -it --network cp-all-in-one_default --name mysql-client --rm mysql mysql -hmysql -udemouser -pdemopass example
```

#### Reproducing

The `teams` and `players` table already exist in my relational database (e.g mysql):

```sql
CREATE TABLE teams(
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    founded INT NOT NULL,
    arena VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    championships INT NOT NULL,
    lastupdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE players(
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    team VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    avg_points DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    born INT NOT NULL,
    lastupdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO teams   (name, founded, arena, championships) VALUES ('eagles',   2020, 'at&t arena',     0);
INSERT INTO teams   (name, founded, arena, championships) VALUES ('vultures', 2019, 'verizon center', 1);
INSERT INTO players (name, team, avg_points, born)        VALUES ('alice', 'vultures', 30, 2013);
INSERT INTO players (name, team, avg_points, born)        VALUES ('bob', 'vultures', 25, 2015);
INSERT INTO players (name, team, avg_points, born)        VALUES ('charlie', 'eagles', 20, 2014);
```

Then I create two connectors using KSQL CLI and create two KSQL tables (all the commands from now on will be in KSQL CLI):

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';

CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR teams WITH(
    "connector.class"='io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector',
    "connection.url"='jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/example?user=demouser&password=demopass',
    "mode"='timestamp',
    "table.whitelist"='teams',
    "timestamp.column.name"='lastupdated',
    "topic.prefix"='jdbc_',
    "transforms"='valueToKey,extractFieldFromKey',
    "transforms.valueToKey.type"='org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey',
    "transforms.valueToKey.fields"='name',
    "transforms.extractFieldFromKey.type"='org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key',
    "transforms.extractFieldFromKey.field"='name',
    "value.converter"='org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
    "key.converter.schemas.enable"='false',
    "value.converter.schemas.enable"='false'
);
-- PRINT jdbc_teams FROM BEGINNING;

CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR players WITH(
    "connector.class"='io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector',
    "connection.url"='jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/example?user=demouser&password=demopass',
    "mode"='timestamp',
    "table.whitelist"='players',
    "timestamp.column.name"='lastupdated',
    "topic.prefix"='jdbc_',
    "transforms"='valueToKey,extractFieldFromKey',
    "transforms.valueToKey.type"='org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey',
    "transforms.valueToKey.fields"='name',
    "transforms.extractFieldFromKey.type"='org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key',
    "transforms.extractFieldFromKey.field"='name',
    "value.converter"='org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
    "key.converter.schemas.enable"='false',
    "value.converter.schemas.enable"='false'
);
-- PRINT jdbc_players FROM BEGINNING;

CREATE TABLE teams(
    name VARCHAR,
    founded INT,
    arena VARCHAR,
    championships INT,
    lastupdated BIGINT
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'jdbc_teams',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
    TIMESTAMP='lastupdated',
    KEY = 'name'
);
-- SELECT * FROM teams EMIT CHANGES;

CREATE TABLE players(
    name VARCHAR,
    team VARCHAR,
    avg_points DOUBLE,
    born INT,
    lastupdated BIGINT
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'jdbc_players',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
    TIMESTAMP='lastupdated',
    KEY = 'name'
);
-- SELECT * FROM players EMIT CHANGES;
```

Now I'd like to join the tables. In KSQL CLI:

```sql
SELECT
    players.name as player,
    teams.name as team,
    avg_points,
    born,
    teams.founded as team_founded,
    arena,
    teams.championships as team_championships
FROM
    teams INNER JOIN players ON teams.name = players.team
EMIT CHANGES;
```

This results in an error:

> Source table (PLAYERS) key column (PLAYERS.NAME) is not the column used in the join criteria (PLAYERS.TEAM). Only the table's key column or 'ROWKEY' is supported in the join criteria.

## Possible solution: collect_list()

One solution may be to "massage" the players table and key it by the team name instead of the player name,
using `collect_list(COLUMN)` and then (after joining with the teams table) `EXPLODE(COLUMN) AS NEW_NAME`:

```sql
SELECT
    team,
    collect_list(name) as players,
    collect_list(avg_points) as avg_points,
    collect_list(born) as born_dates
FROM players
GROUP BY team
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Returns good results:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|TEAM     |PLAYERS      |AVG_POINTS   |BORN_DATES   |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|vultures |[alice]      |[30.0]       |[2013]       |
|vultures |[alice, bob] |[30.0, 25.0] |[2013, 2015] |
|eagles   |[charlie]    |[20.0]       |[2014]       |
```

So we can create a table from the query above and then join on teams:

```sql
CREATE TABLE teamplayers AS
    SELECT
        team,
        collect_list(name) as players,
        collect_list(avg_points) as avg_points,
        collect_list(born) as born_dates
    FROM players
    GROUP BY team;

CREATE TABLE enriched_team_players AS
    SELECT
        team,
        players,
        avg_points,
        born_dates,
        founded,
        arena,
        championships
    FROM teamplayers INNER JOIN teams ON teamplayers.team = teams.name;

SELECT * FROM enriched_team_players EMIT CHANGES;
```

The result is really close to the desired result, and all there's left to do (unless i'm missing something) is to explode the lists.
Here is the result:

```
+--------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
|ROWTIME       |ROWKEY   |TEAM     |PLAYERS      |AVG_POINTS   |BORN_DATES   |FOUNDED |ARENA          |CHAMPIONSHIPS |
+--------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
|1582017691000 |vultures |vultures |[alice, bob] |[30.0, 25.0] |[2013, 2015] |2019    |verizon center |1             |
|1582017691000 |eagles   |eagles   |[charlie]    |[20.0]       |[2014]       |2020    |at&t arena     |0             |
```

Now I'm trying to explode the results with the following query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE desired_result AS
    SELECT
        EXPLODE(players) as player,
        team,
        EXPLODE(avg_points) as avg_points,
        EXPLODE(born_dates) as born,
        founded as team_founded,
        arena,
        championships as team_championships
    FROM enriched_team_players;
```

and I get this in the output:

> source

## How to proceed?

Where is this `source` printed from?

When I `list tables;` I don't see any table called `desired_result`, and when I `list queries;` I don't see a new query that creates this table.
Why don't I get the results for `EXPLODE` as described in [table functions](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/table-functions.html#table-functions)?

Is there another (perhaps simpler) way to get the desired result considering the schema that was given to me in the relational DB (which I don't control)?
The current way uses [collect_list](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html#aggregate-functions), which (for the version 5.4.0 of ksql) supports up tp 1000 entries per row.
In the example above, no team contains more than 1000 players, however, in my real use case, in ~5% of the cases some rows are linked to roughly 10,000 entities.
Is the 1000 limit configurable?
Is there a solution that does not have this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you've run into this bug in the beta release of table-functions:

https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4033

This is fixed in later versions of KSQL.

Also, on a more general note to your original problem...

At the moment you've modeled the two source tables as tables in KSQL. Tables in KSQL only support joins on their primary key. Hence you're running into the 'Only the table's key column or 'ROWKEY' is supported in the join criteria.' error.

Have you considered modeling the `jdbc_players` topic as a stream of changes? Unlike tables, stream can be repartitioned to allow the join you require. This may get you what you want with the version of KSQL you're running. The downside of this approach is that it may not handle deletes from the source tables correctly.

```
-- stream of player changes:
CREATE STREAM player_changes(
    name VARCHAR,
    team VARCHAR,
    avg_points DOUBLE,
    born INT,
    lastupdated BIGINT
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'jdbc_players',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
    TIMESTAMP='lastupdated'
);

-- join:
SELECT * FROM player_changes p JOIN teams t on p.team = t.name;
```